# Custom buttons Action Column, yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I want to change default buttons on ActionColumn (GridView::widget) using modal popup window. here is my code:

```
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 8.7%'],
            'visible'=> Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? false : true,
            'buttons'=>[
                'view'=>function ($url, $model) {
                    $t = 'index.php?r=site/view&id='.$model->id;
                    return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value'=>Url::to($t), 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs', 'id'=>'modalButtonView']);
                },
                'update'=>function ($url, $model) {
                    $t = 'index.php?r=site/update&id='.$model->id;
                    return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['value'=>Url::to($t), 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs', 'id'=>'modalButtonView']);
                },
            ],
        ],
```

Only first button works well, another buttons doesn't. What should I change? And can I use anchor tags instead buttons?
Here are my js and ModalWidget:

```
$(function(){
$('#modalButtonView').click(function(){
    $('#modalView').modal('show').find('#modalContentView').load($(this).attr('value'));

});});


        Modal::begin(['id'=>'modalView', 'size'=>'modal-md']);
    echo "<div id='modalContentView'></div>";
    Modal::end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic rules in html.

ID must unique.

use this code

```
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 8.7%'],
    'visible'=> Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? false : true,
    'buttons'=>[
        'view'=>function ($url, $model) {
            $t = 'index.php?r=site/view&id='.$model->id;
            return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value'=>Url::to($t), 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button']);
        },
        'update'=>function ($url, $model) {
            $t = 'index.php?r=site/update&id='.$model->id;
            return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['value'=>Url::to($t), 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button']);
        },
    ],
],
```

then yor jquery

```
$(function(){
$('.custom_button').click(function(){
    $('#modalView').modal('show').find('#modalContentView').load($(this).attr('value'));

});});

    Modal::begin(['id'=>'modalView', 'size'=>'modal-md']);
echo "<div id='modalContentView'></div>";
Modal::end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using id in your buttons html options... 
Id is unique for Html elements.

Instead of id you have to use class of `modelButtonView` and change your JS according to it..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Html::button (with jquery). You can use Html::a:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 7%'],
            'visible'=> Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? false : true,
            'buttons'=>[
                'view'=>function ($url) {
                    return Html::a('', $url, ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button']);
                },
                'update'=>function ($url) {
                    return Html::a('', $url, ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button']);
                },
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score -2):

this example is easy to understand me
 have one doubt

```
`['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 8.7%'],
                        'visible'=> false,
                        'buttons'=>[
                                'view'=>function ($url, $model) {
                                    $t = 'index.php?r=site/view&id='.$model->id;
                                    return Html::button('', ['value'=>Url::to($t), 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button']);
                                },
                                'update'=>function ($url, $model) {
                                    $t = 'index.php?r=site/update&id='.$model->id;
                                    return Html::button('', ['value'=>Url::to($t), 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button']);
                                },
                                ],
                                ],`
```